# .NET core Semaphore and SemaphoreSlim works on a linux server

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-core

In the microsoft documentation says that the method works on top of win32, I would like to know if I can use it on linux?
If I publish my application with these methods on the linux server could it be a problem?

Comment: Semaphore slim does work on Linux ..we are using it on Linux containers

Comment: Where does the documentation say (or imply) that it only works on Win32?  Does [ApiPort](https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet-apiport#net-api-portability) flag it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run semaphore on linux c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63290287/run-semaphore-on-linux-c-sharp)