# Run semaphore on linux c#

Tags: c#, .net, linux, semaphore

I am running semaphore on linux and is generating the following error:

> "Exception": {"ClassName": "System.PlatformNotSupportedException", "Message": "The named version of this synchronization primitive is not supported on this platform.", "Data": null, "InnerException": null, "HelpURL ": null," StackTraceString ":" at System.Threading.Semaphore.CreateSemaphoreCore (Int32 initialCount, Int32 maximumCount, String name, Boolean & createdNew) \ n at System.Threading.Semaphore..ctor (Int32 initialCount, Int32 maximumCount, String name, Boolean & createdNew) \ n at System.Threading.Semaphore..ctor (Int32 initialCount, Int32 maximumCount, String name) \ n "," RemoteStackTraceString ": null," RemoteStackIndex ": 0," ExceptionMethod ": null," HResult ": - 2146233031," Source ":" System.Private.CoreLib "," WatsonBuckets ": null},

Can someone help me?

Comment: Do you actually need a named one?

Comment: I need it because it will lock according to a specific token. Example:
1 - abcd123 - running
2 - abcd123 - locked
3 - 7895aa - running

Comment: You may store semaphores in global `ConcurrentDictionary<string, SemaphoreSlim>`, the key will be the name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux doesn't support named synchronization primitives, so neither does .NET Core.

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/5211

UPDATE
*Based on comments*

As of .NET 5, named semaphores are still unsupported. I haven't tested other primitives.

***NET 6** update*

Named semaphores are still not supported, but named Mutexes works fine at least for MacOS

[image]

Comment: You might want to edit your post since named Mutexes can now be used in Linux.
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/5030

Comment: @julealgon The source code still has `SupportedOSPlatformAttribute("windows")` and a test under Ubuntu just how threw `PlatformNotSupportedException`. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading/ref/System.Threading.cs

Comment: I think you are mistaken Eric. The latest version definitely supports named mutexes on Linux. I don't think thats where the file actually is (though I can't find it myself).

Comment: @julealgon Did you try it out?

Comment: I've not personally tried, no, but I've read at least one report from someone who was actively using named mutexes on Linux while I was looking into this a few days ago.

Comment: See image added. As of .NET 5, it does not work.

Comment: Eric, I explicitly said that it should work with mutexes only, not semaphores. The .NET team decided not to implement named semaphores in Linux due to potential system resource leaks associated with it. Can you please test again with a named `Mutex`?